# Firebase service account private key exposed to admin.firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I configured firebase admin in my node.js backend into a variable called `admin`, and I call `admin.firestore()`. When I do `console.log(admin.firestore())`, I see my private key of my service account been displayed in the back-end terminal. Here is the console log I see:

```
Firestore {
  _settings: {
    credentials: {
      private_key: 'my actual private key',
      client_email: 'xxxxx'
    },
    projectId: 'pxxxx3',
    firebaseVersion: '8.13.0',
    libName: 'gccl',
    libVersion: '3.8.6 fire/8.13.0'
  },
  _settingsFrozen: false,
  _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function], allowUndefined: false },
  _projectId: 'xxxxx',
  registeredListenersCount: 0,
  _lastSuccessfulRequest: 0,
  _backoffSettings: { initialDelayMs: 100, maxDelayMs: 60000, backoffFactor: 1.3 },
  _preferTransactions: false,
  _clientPool: ClientPool {
    concurrentOperationLimit: 100,
    maxIdleClients: 1,
    clientFactory: [Function],
    clientDestructor: [Function],
    activeClients: Map {},
    terminated: false,
    terminateDeferred: Deferred {
      resolve: [Function],
      reject: [Function],
      promise: [Promise]
    }
  }
}
```

I am a bit concerned that it might be a security risk. Although it is within the codes in my backend. But should I be concerned?

Comment: Saw this as well when debugging firebase admin sdk from AWS lambda function. after `snapshot = await db.collection('test').get()` all credentials are in `snapshot` too. Not that I will return it to a client, just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is only ever available on your backend, then it is "secure" in that only people who have permission to access your backend can see it.  The problem is not that the data is in the log, the problem is in who you allow to see that log.

If the data never escapes to a client app, then you don't have to worry about random people on the internet from seeing your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if an external entity can log into your system, you have a different kind of problem.

If you think about it, most of the environment variables have to be placed somewhere during runtime. They should not be hardcoded in your code, but in runtime, you need a mechanism to ensure the values are copied into your system. After that, it's all about authorization, only users with the right permissions should be allowed to get into your system.